# Dropdown list by bootstrap4 is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, content-security-policy

I'm working on Rails and bootstrap4. I created the dropdown menu at navbar by bootstrap but it doesn't work.

So I checked the inspect and noticed that chrome showed an error message.

"Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

It seems my codes have no problem.

_header.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <%= ApplicationHelper::APP_NAME %>
  </a>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <%= link_to("#", id: "navbarDropdownMenuLink", class: "nav-link dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle": "dropdown", "data-flip": "true", "aria-haspopup": "false", "aria-expanded": "false") do %>
          <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url, class: "rounded-circle", style: "width: 50px;" %>
        <% end %>

        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="position: absolute;right: 0;left: auto;">
          <%= link_to "Edit your profile", edit_user_registration_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
          <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

application.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require tether
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I expected it's related by the below message.

"Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

So I googled and paste below line into application.html.erb .

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'">
```

But dropdown list still not working and this message is also still displayed.

I'd like to know how to solve it and what this message means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your problem is really related to CSP, but in any case it's always a good idea to set one. Note that setting the CSP via meta tag is less secure and as such, it is recommended to use the corresponding HTTP headers instead.

Rails already includes an [(undocumented) middleware](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/759b3af0c6fc9fb502031a05b281736602ff8e5f/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb#L100) for generating these.

Since it looks like you are using scripts from your Rails application, I would assume that adding `script-src 'self'` should indeed do the trick. Since it does not: are you loading JS files from external sources by any chance? Especially vendor-hosted CDNs are quite popular. Try checking your browsers network request tab to find out whether it makes any requests to external sources.

If it does, you'll need to add those to the CSP. Getting all aspects of a CSP right can be a bit daunting at first but once you get better acquainted with it, it can be a useful tool for securing your application.

Comment: I've already installed secure_headers gem and set secure_headers.rb under config/initializers by default setting. 

`SecureHeaders::Configuration.default`

It prevented loading external JS files. I tried uninstalling secure_headers gem and reload the page, and then JS files loaded and dropdown list works fine. Today I faced CSP for the first time, so after the understanding about that I'll try using CSP and secure_headers gem. Thank you for your advice.